# How to use jQuery .one with .scroll?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want this ajax to load only when there's a scroll event, but only one time (instead of every time the user scrolls.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/reviews"
    })
      .done(function( html ) {
        $( "#reviews-ajax" ).append(html);
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(window).one('scroll', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/reviews"
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $( "#reviews-ajax" ).append(html);
    });
});
```

> **`one()`**
>
> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   **at most once per element per event type**.

Comment: Wow!  That's awesome.  I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: [It does all things](https://i.reddituploads.com/b79bb2d6e2f14e65b769686647cc4782?fit=max&h=1536&w=1536&s=ed6be616a7a0467c49330eda9253811e) !

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var flag = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(flag == 0){
            flag = 1;
            $.ajax({
               url: "/reviews"
            })
           .done(function( html ) {
              $( "#reviews-ajax" ).append(html);
            });
        }
     }); 
});
```